# Getting error 503 after unexpected shut down of zammad server

Tags: server, apache2

Infos:

- Used Zammad version: 6.2.0-1704877727.2bda00c4.focal
- Used Zammad installation type: package
  Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04
  Browser + version: Brave, Edge, Firefox

I am running Zammad instance in virtual box. The host is a windows 10. After force restart of Windows due to update i started the VM with Zammad again. Normally works without problem but now i am getting error 503 in the browser.
In the apache2 logs i see that there is a problem with one of the web services with zammad:

```
[Fri Jan 12 12:58:11.766781 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 1057:tid 140234859714304] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Fri Jan 12 12:58:11.766820 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1057:tid 140234859714304] [client 192.168.178.39:60787] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Fri Jan 12 12:58:12.489425 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 1057:tid 140234842928896] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Fri Jan 12 12:58:12.489467 2024] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1057:tid 140234842928896] [client 192.168.178.39:60788] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

the service that runs on the loopback on port 3000 is: zammad-web.service
This is confirmed in ss -tulpen

```
    Netid     State      Recv-Q     Send-Q                               Local Address:Port           Peer Address:Port     Process
udp       UNCONN     0          0                                    127.0.0.53%lo:53                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=699,fd=12)) uid:101 ino:21708 sk:1 <->
udp       UNCONN     0          0                            192.168.178.65%enp0s3:68                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-network",pid=697,fd=19)) uid:100 ino:23741 sk:2 <->
udp       UNCONN     0          0                [fe80::a00:27ff:feec:3515]%enp0s3:546                    [::]:*         users:(("systemd-network",pid=697,fd=20)) uid:100 ino:23798 sk:3 v6only:1 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          80                                       127.0.0.1:3306                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("mysqld",pid=906,fd=18)) uid:114 ino:26342 sk:4 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          10                                       127.0.0.1:587                 0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sendmail-mta",pid=1201,fd=5)) ino:27911 sk:5 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          511                                      127.0.0.1:6379                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("redis-server",pid=998,fd=6)) uid:116 ino:24554 sk:6 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                                 127.0.0.53%lo:53                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=699,fd=13)) uid:101 ino:21709 sk:7 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          128                                        0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sshd",pid=925,fd=3)) ino:26789 sk:8 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          10                                       127.0.0.1:25                  0.0.0.0:*         users:(("sendmail-mta",pid=1201,fd=4)) ino:27910 sk:9 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          100                                      127.0.0.1:6042                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("ruby",pid=8569,fd=9)) uid:997 ino:64526 sk:a <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          511                                          [::1]:6379                   [::]:*         users:(("redis-server",pid=998,fd=7)) uid:116 ino:24555 sk:b v6only:1 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                            [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:9200                      *:*         users:(("java",pid=719,fd=162)) uid:115 ino:28420 sk:c v6only:0 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                                         [::1]:9200                   [::]:*         users:(("java",pid=719,fd=161)) uid:115 ino:28419 sk:d v6only:1 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          511                                              *:80                        *:*         users:(("apache2",pid=1060,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1059,fd=4),("apache2",pid=1058,fd=4)) ino:28683 sk:e v6only:0 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                            [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:9300                      *:*         users:(("java",pid=719,fd=159)) uid:115 ino:30734 sk:f v6only:0 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          4096                                         [::1]:9300                   [::]:*         users:(("java",pid=719,fd=158)) uid:115 ino:30727 sk:10 v6only:1 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          128                                           [::]:22                     [::]:*         users:(("sshd",pid=925,fd=4)) ino:26791 sk:11 v6only:1 <->
tcp       LISTEN     0          511                                              *:443                       *:*         users:(("apache2",pid=1060,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1059,fd=6),("apache2",pid=1058,fd=6)) ino:28687 sk:12 v6only:0 <->
```

no port 3000.

systemctl shows that the service is up and running though:

```
sudo systemctl status zammad-web
● zammad-web.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/zammad-web.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-01-12 16:35:39 UTC; 3h 48min ago
Main PID: 759 (sleep)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 9425)
Memory: 264.0K
CGroup: /system.slice/zammad-web.service
└─759 /bin/sleep infinity

Jan 12 16:35:39 helpdeskadmin systemd[1]: Started zammad-web.service.
```

I tried killing it with PID without success

```
ps aux | grep zammad-web.service
helpdes+  148790  0.0  0.0   6440   720 pts/0    S+   09:35   0:00 grep --color=auto zammad-web.service

sudo kill 148790
kill: (148790): No such process
```

...cannot find it, so I ran `sudo journalctl -xe` and it seems to me that the service is restarting itself very fast and going in death state.

```
A start job for unit zammad-web-1.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 505980.
Jan 14 13:33:42 helpdeskadmin zammad-web-1.service[172119]: Could not find server ''.
Jan 14 13:33:42 helpdeskadmin zammad-web-1.service[172119]: Run `bin/rails server --help` for more options.
Jan 14 13:33:42 helpdeskadmin systemd[1]: zammad-web-1.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit zammad-web-1.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jan 14 13:33:42 helpdeskadmin systemd[1]: zammad-web-1.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5313.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit zammad-web-1.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jan 14 13:33:42 helpdeskadmin systemd[1]: Stopped zammad-web-1.service.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit zammad-web-1.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit zammad-web-1.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 506075 and the job result is done.
Jan 14 13:33:42 helpdeskadmin systemd[1]: Started zammad-web-1.service.
-- Subject: A start job for unit zammad-web-1.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit zammad-web-1.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 506075.
Jan 14 13:33:43 helpdeskadmin sudo[172089]: helpdeskadmin : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/helpdeskadmin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -xe
Jan 14 13:33:43 helpdeskadmin sudo[172089]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by helpdeskadmin(uid=0)
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: excuse formatting, first time i post something outside instagram....